# Is this question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Is it okay to ask a question here that is actually more specific than an earlier question on the *same subject matter*?

My question:
[Who developed the doctrine of Biblical Inerrancy first - Catholics or Protestants?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36971/who-developed-the-doctrine-of-inerrancy-first-catholics-or-protestants)

Their question:
[What is the history of the doctrine of inerrancy?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/27698/what-is-the-history-of-the-doctrine-of-inerrancy?lq=1)

I think my question would be marked as a duplicate. Yet, my question is actually more *specific* than the previous and includes something that the previous question overlooks. If they are duplicates, can a more specific question be kept while the broader question gets closed?

Answer (score 1):

Generally questions which are subsets should be marked as duplicates of questions which are broader. I think this is definitely the case for your question. Now the exact info you're after may not be present in any answer of the other question, but there are a few things you could do:

- Comment on the question
- Comment on an answer whose author you think is most likely to know the answer
- Start a bounty on the question asking for specific info

In your specific case one of the tricky things is that inerrency and infallibility are something considered to be basically synonymous and sometimes not. It would be good to ask whether Catholics and Protestants use the words different, but that should be done in a separate question to asking about the history.

Comment: There is one problem: will the asker still be active?

Comment: I also found another earlier question. http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15638/when-was-the-bible-formally-declared-to-be-inerrant-and-or-infallible But the answer does not satisfy me, because it's too scriptural. It does not even mention actual history or clear the ambiguity.